# How to add reply link under every comment?

Tags: 8, theming, comments

[image]

I using standart Drupal 8 module for comments. Can I add reply link under comments or I have to install another module?

I'm log in **as administrator**, but i dont see edit/delete/reple link

[image]

Help please!

Comment: did you check that your connected user has `post comments` permission ?

Comment: Yes, I cheked..

Comment: I using Drupal core 8.6.1

Comment: ok , Go to `admin/structure/comment/manage/comment/display`  and check if links not under `Disabled` ?

Comment: you are welcome, i will post it as answer if someone needs it in the future .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to *admin/structure/comment/manage/comment/display* and make sure that **Links** not **Disabled** .